# Compare fields of same model

Tags: django, mongodb, orm

I have this model:

```
#Model for match result forecast
class ResultForecast(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('match date', blank=True, null=True)
    home_goals = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)
    away_goals = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, related_name='forecasted_match')
```

So I wanna get the objects where de home_goals are greater than the away goals and vice versa, I use this:

```
total_forecast = ResultForecast.objects.filter(match=match).count()
home_trend =  ResultForecast.objects.filter(match=match, home_goals__gt=F('away_goals'))
away_trend = ResultForecast.objects.filter(match=match, away_goals__gt=F('home_goals'))
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering if match should actually be match__exact? Have you tried the following to see if it makes any difference? I also prefer to use the Q class. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/

```
from django.db.models import Q

    home_trend =  ResultForecast.objects.filter(
        Q(match__exact=match) & 
        Q(home_goals__gt=F('away_goals')))

    away_trend = ResultForecast.objects.filter(
        Q(match__exact=match) & 
        Q(away_goals__gt=F('home_goals')))
```